# Как прочитать файл txt на java

Tags: java, файлы

Есть однострочный *txt* файл.

Как считать из файла одну строку и присвоить `String` переменной это значение?

Answer (score 3):

**Java8**

Если тебе надо иммено первую строчку прочитать    :

```
String fileName = "file.txt";
Optional<String> line = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName)).findFirst();
System.out.println(line.get());
```

Если надо прочитать весь файл:

```
String fileName = "file.txt";
String content = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName)).reduce("", String::concat);
System.out.println(content);
```

Comment: лучше бы `.findFirst().orElse(null);`

Comment: или line.ifPresent(System.out::print);
Все равно прийдеться проверять на наличие строки как не крути

Comment: Тогда и так тоже не плохо `Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName)).forEach(System.out::println);` для всех строк

Comment: 2 способ- если надо считать весь файл - тогда в content будет весь файл, заключенный в одну строчку? А что с переносами на новую строчку и tab-ами? Они будут в виде системных символов в строке или проигнорируются?

Comment: Да, будет одна строка. Если надо сохранить переносимость строк то можно написать так `.reduce("",(a,b) -> a + "\n" + b);`

Answer (score 3):

Есть несколько способов, можете выбрать любой, в зависимости от версии java.

- Явно создать `BufferedReader`:

  ```
  try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName)))  {
      String value = reader.readLine();
  }
  ```
- Воспользоваться утилитным классом `Files`:

  ```
  try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(fileName))) { 
      String value = reader.readLine();
  }
  ```
- Использовать `Stream API` :

  ```
  try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
      Optional<String> optional = stream.findFirst();
      String value = optional.isPresent() ? optional.get() : null;
  }
  ```

Comment: `Files.lines` тоже нужно использовать с `try-with-resources`

Comment: @iksuy не знал. Спасибо за замечание.

Answer (score 2):

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/foo/bar/file.txt"));
String s = br.readLine();
br.close();
```

плюс уделить внимание checked исключениям, либо указав их в `throws` в объявлении метода, либо обернув конструкцию в `try-catch`